# Is there a way to tell if user used MFA from Azure AD logs

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

Searching through MS documentation on Azure login logs information meanings and cannot find anything that matches what I am looking for.

I have a user who "successfully" logged into their account via OAuth2, "UserAuthenticationMethod": "1" (which should be password use)
The account has MFA enabled, I want to confirm that the user is using MFA and it was not bypassed in anyway or confirm that this was a refresh login from a token but cannot find any definitive information in the logs.

If anyone could point me to some documentation or even third party guides at this point would be a life saver.

I apologize if this post is in the wrong area, first time posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the MFA result under Azure MFA reports. It may not include every detail but it will show all usage and bypass history. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-reporting

MFA Result: More information on whether MFA was satisfied or denied:

If MFA was satisfied, this column provides more information about how MFA was satisfied.

Azure Multi-Factor Authentication
completed in the cloud
has expired due to the policies configured on tenant
registration prompted
satisfied by claim in the token
satisfied by claim provided by external provider
satisfied by strong authentication
skipped as flow exercised was Windows broker logon flow
skipped due to app password
skipped due to location
skipped due to registered device
skipped due to remembered device
successfully completed
Redirected to external provider for multi-factor authentication

The [sign-ins report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-reporting#azure-ad-sign-ins-report) will also answer:

Was the sign-in challenged with MFA?
How did the user complete MFA?
Why was the user unable to complete MFA?
How many users are challenged for MFA?
How many users are unable to complete the MFA challenge?
What are the common MFA issues end users are running into?